# MVC Get View HTML output in Test Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I get generated HTML (View) in my Test Method?

I have the following:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
```

Test:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void HomeControllerReturnsView()
    {
        // Arrange
        var controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, "Home");
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            var test = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

FYI: when i run this in debug controller.HttpContext and controller.RouteData are null.
thanks

Comment: Voting to reopen - I guess it was closed because it is unclear what part of the unit test fails... but question itself looks interesting to me ("how get html as result of View in unit test").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to execute the views inside the unit test. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html) in which David Ebbo illustrates this.

But those are no longer unit tests. They are integration tests and you could use tools such as [Watin](http://watin.org/) which could allow you to perform integration tests on your application.